# Pattern matching or other method to exclude packages from shell script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

On macOS, I've been using an Automator workflow saved as a Service to run the following bash script:

```
for dir; do
cd "$dir"
"$HOME"/fixFoldersDateMod "$dir"
done
```

This runs a `fixFoldersDateMod` command script on the folder(s) selected in Finder to fix the last modified date of folder structures, recursively setting all folders to the most recent modification date of all files/folders contained within them.

But recently, I ran the workflow on a folder with some packages in it, and all the packages and the folders within them were also modified! Now I'm trying to find a way to modify the script to exclude various packages and their contents based on their extension.

Here's the modified script I've tried to do this with (not working properly):

```
temp=(vst|vst3|app|component|aaxplugin|dpm)
pattern="(^|:)$temp(:|$)"
for dir; do
if [[ ! $dir =~ $pattern ]] ; then
  continue;
fi
cd "$dir"
"$HOME"/fixFoldersDateMod "$dir"
done
```

I'm not sure how to format the regex or pattern matching for shell script properly. But ideally, if this were to work correctly, upon selecting a folder in Finder and running this workflow service, any package matching the list of package extensions `(vst|vst3|app|component|aaxplugin|dpm)` and their contents would be excluded from being processed by the `fixFoldersDateMod` script in my home folder.

e.g.

```
(selected folder/path - excluded?)
"/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/iZotope" - No
"/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/iZotope/Insight.vst" - Yes
"/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/Zynaptiq" - No
"/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/Zynaptiq/UNVEIL AU.component" - Yes
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here, and how to get it working properly?

And on a related note, how can I get the Service to run the command script using **sudo** (prompting for my password if necessary) so it'll also work on system folders?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach that might suit your requirements would be to leverage a bash `case` statement and a parameter expansion.  Use process the output of a `find` command and extract the file extension.  Then skip if the extension is part of the to-exclude list, otherwise, adjust the modified time. Something like:

```
find "$work" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do 
    case "${f##*.}" in
        vst | vst3 | app | component | aaxplugin | dpm)
            ;; # skipping
        *)
            echo "adjust modified time for $f"
    esac
done
```

Full example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

work=$(mktemp -d)

setup() {
    touch "$work/foo.bar"
    touch "$work/bar.baz"
    touch "$work/baz.foo"
    for ext in "vst" "vst3" "app" "component" "aaxplugin" "dpm"; do
        touch "$work/sample.$ext" 
    done
}

cleanup() {      
  rm -rf "$work"
  echo "Deleted temp working directory $work"
}

trap cleanup EXIT

setup

find "$work" -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do 
    case "${f##*.}" in
        vst | vst3 | app | component | aaxplugin | dpm)
            ;; # skipping
        *)
            echo "adjust modified time for $f"
    esac
done
```

Output:

```
adjust modified time for /tmp/tmp.C3t3K1p4jS/foo.bar
adjust modified time for /tmp/tmp.C3t3K1p4jS/bar.baz
adjust modified time for /tmp/tmp.C3t3K1p4jS/baz.foo
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it may work quite well. I'll have to test once I finish some currently pressing tasks to be sure. But either way, thanks for some code that I'm sure will help me to resolve this issue. :)